# make: *** No rule to make target `install_abci'. Stop

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

I am trying to install abci-app ( kvstore ) using command `make install_abci`
but i am getting error as:

```
make:  No rule to make target `install_abci'.  Stop.
```

I'm unable to identify why i am getting this error. is  there any alternate method to install abci-app.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a link to this software or copy the Makefile you are using?

Comment: i am using link **https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/blob/master/docs/app-dev/getting-started.md** and trying to follow the steps to install tendermint

Comment: You are in the folder where the Makefile lies, right?

Comment: yes, i'm in the same folder

Comment: The rule exists. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. 

install_abci:
 @go install ./abci/cmd/...

Answer (score 1):

run `make install_abci` in the main tendermint directory currently works on develop. Did you run `make get_tools`, that installs protoc which you need.